# Extrapolate 95% CI for unit decrease and for percentage decrease from lmer outputs

Tags: r, confidence-interval, percentage, ggplot2, effects

I am testing the association between percentage of impervious surface areas (ISA) and number of eggs per breeding event. This is my model structure:

```
fit=lmer(CS~ISA+Mass_Fem*LayDate+Year+(1|Site),data=DataGT_noNA)
```

Where CS is clutch size, ISA is imperviousness (as %), mass female is the female body mass  in grams, Lay date is an ordinal number, and Year is a 5-levels factor. The random effect "Site" has 8 levels.

After obtaining the estimates of loss by a certain %ISA using ggplot and ggeffects as follows:

```
effects_ISA <- effects::effect(term= "ISA", mod= fit, xlevels=list(ISA=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70)))
```

I made a dataframe containing all these values as follows

```
x_ISA <- as.data.frame(effects_ISA)
```

and obtained this table as a result:

[image]

I would like to obtain the unit decrease (and respective confidence intervals) in terms of number of eggs (including 95% CI) by a given percentage of ISA. See example below:

An increase of 30% of ISA, corresponds to a 0.54 (CI95??) loss in number of eggs. I would like to get the same info as a percentage (% loss and % CI95%)